# datetime keeps updating when record is updated - need it to remain at original creation date

Tags: mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin, timestamp

i've got a problem i can't seem to figure out - and yes, i've searched & searched for an answer here & google.

i'm a complete noob with php & mysql, so please be gentle & detailed.

i've got a form that, when submitted, the "created date" is recorded along with everything else that was submitted.

that "created date" is displayed on the form results page.

i have it so that the users can edit their entry, and i have a "last updated date" that's recorded if/when they update their record.

the "last updated" works fine. the "created date" keeps updating along with the "last updated" field. i can't keep the "created date" to remain what it 'was' if the record is updated.

below are screenshots of the two fields in phpmyadmin.

i had a friend initially set this up for me & he is unavailable to ask.
along with the question, i'm curious about how he might've gotten the "Extra" column filled in as it's not an option on the edit page.

THANKS in advance!!!

PS: apparently, i'm not allowed to upload screenshots cause i'm a newbie. here are 2 links to the 2 screenshots...

1) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/95838/ScreenShot1.png

2) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/95838/ScreenShot2.png

Answer (score 0):

First, he could be doing something to update the field in the background even though it's not displayed on the page using the application code.

Second, there could be a trigger on the field that updates the timestamp whenever something is changed.  Triggers fire during an update/delete/insert event. More info on triggers here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

I'd look for a trigger in phpmyadmin first, barring that it's something in the application code.

Comment: i don't think so. i don't see anything in the code that has anything to do with date or time, & the only place i see anything bout the "created" & "updated" fields are the php lines to have them display with everything else. and with regards to the trigger thing, i found via google to type "SHOW TRIGGERS" in the SQL section of phpmyadmin for that table. it says it was successful, but it doesn't show anything. so i guess that means there are no triggers.

Answer (score 0):

In `Extra` You have `On Update Current_TimeStamp` <- take that out and you are good to go

Comment: thanks but, as you can see in the 2nd screenshot, there's no way that i can find to edit the "Extra" field.

Comment: The Extra field refers to `Attributes` when u are editing that column.

Comment: AH! good to know. thanks! interestingly tho, the "Attributes" pulldown menu doesn't have this option. only "Binary", "Unsigned", & "Unsigned Zerofill". i've noticed in other screenshots around that it is there for some people. so i updated my phpmyadmin to the latest version, but it still doesn't have it. very confused. ALSO note: in copy/pasting queries from google searches, i ended up trying it without that attribute, but the results were the same.

Comment: In that case i would suggest trying to remove the NULL on that field if not then try dumping the database and recreating the table by hand (atleast thats what i would do) and then import just the inserts, to see if that helps fix it. Or you can do a dump of just the table structure and post that.